# Recipe to run on deployment and standalone

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

I have a recipe below (`migrate.rb`) which is run as part of our deployment and works perfectly.

However one thing that I can't workout is how to set it up so it can also be run as a standalone recipe in the `execute_recipe` command.

As it stands if we execute this recipe as a stand alone then nothing happens since the `node[:deploy].each` has nothing to loop over (the deploy key doesn't exist)..

The only part that actually relies on the deploy node is this line `cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"` since I need to know where the code was deployed to.

```rb
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|

  execute 'DB migrate then seed' do
    cwd "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
    command 'php artisan migrate; while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do php artisan db:seed --class="$line"; done < "app/database/run.list"'
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would relocate that part to a definition (or a provider). So basically split your recipe in two parts:

recipes/deploy.rb:

```
node[:deploy].each do |application, deploy|
  php_artisan_setup do
    dir "#{deploy[:deploy_to]}/current"
  end
end
```

definitions/php_artisan_setup.rb:

```
define :php_artisan_setup do
  execute 'DB migrate then seed' do
    cwd params[:dir]
    command 'php artisan migrate; while read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do php artisan db:seed --class="$line"; done < "app/database/run.list"'
  end
end
```

This way, you can call `php_artisan_setup` from your "standalone" recipe, too. You still need two recipes, but you dont have to duplicate the relevant part.